# CPU usage command for monitor script

Tags: monitoring, unix, freebsd, central-processing-unit

Is there a command for FreeBSD (except the `top -P`) I could use to monitor my dedicated server CPU usage? I am in progress of writting my bash script which will notify me as soon as any of the CPU core will be reaching 100% usage.

Thats why I need some other command than `top -P` because it takes some time for the `top` to calculate the usage on the first run and than wouldnt work for per usage command.

Comment: Have you considered running a real monitoring system, like Munin (in the ports tree)?

Comment: Or monit?  Which, is a nice light tool.

Comment: It is not easy to write this script in bash. Quick example on perl: https://gist.github.com/citrin/9411934

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPU load information can be obtained in shell script from `sysctl kern.cp_times`. This is commulative counters, and to get load in % you need  derivative, e. g. get kern.cp_times with 1 minute interval and divide counters by 60.

But more easy to use existing monitoring systems like Nagios (there are many monitoring systems, but no perfect and I can't suggest best system).

Answer (score 1):

You could always install `sysstat`

Then do the following: `sar -u | grep 'Average' | awk '{print 100-$8}'`

Which will take 100 & remove the idle percent.

Comment: There is no `sar` on the FreeBSD systems.